# Spring Rest API not showing nested list results

Tags: java, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have an issue with my Spring Rest API application. 
I have 3 entities like that :

Geometry.java

```
  @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name="sw_geometries")
    public class Geometry{

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Geometry_Generator")
        @SequenceGenerator(name="Geometry_Generator", sequenceName = "Geometry_Sequence")
        private long id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="geometry",
                   cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<Multi> multies = new ArrayList<Multi>();
        }
```

Multi.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="sw_multis")
public class Multi{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Multi_Generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="Multi_Generator", sequenceName = "Multi_Sequence")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="geometry_id")
    private Geometry geometry;
     @Column(name="geometry_id", updatable=false,insertable=false)
     private Long geometryId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="multi",
               cascade= CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
}
```

Location.java

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name="sw_locations")
    public class Location {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Location_Generator")
        @SequenceGenerator(name="Location_Generator", sequenceName = "Location_Sequence")
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne@JoinColumn(name="multi_id")
        private Multi multi;
         @Column(name="multi_id", updatable=false,insertable=false)
            private Long multiId;
 Point.java <br>
        @Embedded
        private Point point;

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            boolean hasNoPoint = (point == null);
            boolean hasNoPointCoord = (point !=null & point.getLatitude() ==null && point.getLongitude() == null);
            return hasNoPoint || hasNoPointCoord;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Location [point=" + point.toString() + "]";
        }

    }
```

Point.java

```
  @Data
    @Embeddable
    public class Point {

        @Column(name = "latitude")
        private Double latitude;

        @Column(name = "longitude")
        private Double longitude;

        @Column(name = "x")
        private Float x;

        @Column(name = "y")
        private Float y;

    }
```

When I print the result of my objects using sysout, everything seems okay and I can see the location printed for every multi (Overrided toString) 
 
[image]

but when I use a rest client to show the resulted jsonI find that locations are not displayed.

[image]

Any ideas please ?

Comment: toString method in Multi.java?

Comment: ` @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("\nclass Multi {\n");
    locations.forEach(l->{
     sb.append(l.toString());
    });
    sb.append("    ").append(toIndentedString(super.toString())).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }`